# Railsで関係ない他のモデルのデータをViewにf.selectで表示する方法。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsとslimを使って開発をしています。
viewに他のモデルのデータをselectするところがありますが、他のモデルの値を持ってくるのができますでようか。

例えば、bookというモデルのpaymentというモデルがあるとします。
２つのモデルには何のリレーションもない状態です。
ここで私がしたいのは
bookの情報を登録するフォームで決済手段を選べるようにしたいんです。
paymentから決済手段の種類を持ってきてそれをフォームのselectのoptionで表示するようにできますでしょうか。

下記は自分のview部分のコードです。（モデルやコントローラーなどはscaffoldで生成しました。）

```
= form_for @book do |f|
  div.form-group 
    .field
      = f.label :番号
      = f.text_field :book_code, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter...'
```

Answer (score 1):

いくつか選択肢はあると思いますが、`fields_for` を使う方法を紹介したいと思います。

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :xxxx %>
  <%= fields_for :payment do |pf| %>
    <%= pf.select :payment_method, @Payment.all  %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "登録" %>
<% end %>
```

例えばこのようなフォームを構成するとサーバー側へのリクエストはrailsのコントローラで処理する時点では

```
params => { "book" => { ..... },
            "payment" => {"payment_method" => "....", ...}}
```

みたいな具合に整形されていると思います。
で、それぞれに

```
@book = User.new(params[:book])
payment_method = params[:payment][:payment_method]
```

などとでもすれば必要な情報が取れるんじゃないかと。
※この例ではストロングパラメタの部分は無視してますのでご注意下さい。

Answer (score 0):

Railsのレールの沿うようなコードを書くのがベストなので、accepts_nested_attributes_forを使えるように書いてみるとよいと思います。

FYI:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_forの場合はリレーションを持つ時に使うものだと思っていましたが、上のように全然関係のないモデルでもaccepts_nested_attributes_forを使うんですか？

Comment: いえ、relationship(belongs_toや{has,has_many}_one)を持っているmodelにしか使えません。
ですので設計をもう一度考えなおしてbelongsや{has,has_many}_oneを使うべき仕様にするかもう一度考えなおすとよいと思います。
relationshipが無いのにmodelとmodelがお互いのデータを使うような仕様を作るのは設計ミスだと考えられます。
まず設計を見なおして @cul8er さんのコードを参考にし、もう一度書きなおしてみてください :D